# Moving Camel Spring XML to Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I would like to move several of our camel application to Spring Boot.  Most of the examples I find are using the java dsl.  The application we currently support are all based on Spring XML.

What steps should I take to migrate these application to Spring Boot.  If I use FatJarRouter it is my understanding that a camel context is auto-cofigured already, so it seems to me I should be able to just define routes in spring xml.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:camel-context.xml")
public class CamelApplication extends FatJarRouter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    String myBean() {
        return "I'm Spring bean!";
    }
}
```

camel-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
    <routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="test">
            <from uri="timer://trigger"/>
            <transform>
                <simple>ref:myBean</simple>
            </transform>
            <to uri="log:out"/>
        </route>
    </routes>
</beans>
```

Exception

```
2015-11-13 15:59:13.734  WARN 2156 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [routes]
Offending resource: class path resource [camel-context.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:60) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: Yeah we should make this easier. I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9325

Comment: Should I still use the FatJarRouter?

Answer (score 2):

See the bottom of this page how to include XML routes:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Spring+Boot

Comment: Hi Claus, I am wondering what will be the best practice. As I am getting to write all the routes from scrach in Spring Boot, I am pondering on the following. 1) If i write the routes or rest dsl in xml they will be in one place . but it i will be not be as per the spring best practices which is against any xml. I feel reading routes in xml is more easy too. 2) If i write routes in camel dsl is there any advantage. Is there anybody debating on this ? any links.

Comment: "Goodbye XML, hello Java DSL" is what is stated in http://joaodiogovicente.blogspot.in/2015/04/rest-with-camel-215.html .
This give some indications around the direction newer code is embracing.

Comment: @davsclaus

Here is a confusion on how to add REST-XML DSL part. This above link states **"The Rest-DSL XML files should be Camel XML rests (not CamelContext) such as" 
where as [link] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_camel_development_guide/restservices-restdsl

states : _italic_ XML, to define a service with the XML DSL, define a rest element as a child of the camelContext element.